# Mock a Function Component with API call and Redux

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, web-applications, jestjs, enzyme

I have a App.js file as

```
const App = props => {
  const {
    userProfile,
    fetchUserProfile
  } = props
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserProfile()
  }, [])
  return userProfile === null ? <></> : <Dashboard />
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  userProfile: state.userProfile
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App)
```

fetchUserProfile Implementation is like below: It is a **Redux action**

```
export const fetchUserProfile = () => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get(`/xxx/userProfile/`)
    .then(resp =>
      dispatch({
        type: SET_PROFILE,
        payload: resp.data,
      }),
    )
    .catch(e => {
      if (e.response?.status === 403) {
        redirectToLogin() /// Redirect the window to a new URL for login
      }
    })
}
```

Store:

```
export default createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)),
)
```

I installed jest and enzyme to unit test this class and other classes:

My Tried Code: Import statement are below

```
import "jest-dom/extend-expect";
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
```

First Code

```
beforeAll(() => {
  global.fetch = jest.fn();
  //window.fetch = jest.fn(); if running browser environment
});

let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
  jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    useSelector: jest.fn(),
    useDispatch: () => mockDispatch
  }));
  jest.mock('./redux/actions', () => ({
    fetchUserProfile: jest.fn(() => useDispatch({
      type: SET_PROFILE,
      payload: {
        "user_id": "myuserid",
        "username": "username",
        "email": "emailID",
        "date_joined": "2020-07-23T18:41:43+00:00",
        "is_staff_user": false,
        "is_super_user": false
      },
    }))
  }))
  
  wrapper = shallow(<App />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
});

afterEach(() => {
  wrapper.unmount();
});
```

Error Thrown

```
Details:

    SyntaxError: /Users/jatingarg/PATH/src/App.test.js: Unexpected token (40:20)

      38 |   }))
      39 |   
    > 40 |   wrapper = shallow(<App />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
         |                     ^
      41 | });
      42 | 
      43 | afterEach(() => {
```

This API uses a token which is cached in the Browser.

Can someone suggest what is the right approach to test this?

I am a noob on ReactJS

Comment: Have you tried `wrapper = shallow((<App />), { disableLifecycleMethods: true });`?

Comment: it throws Same Error after making the change also